# jQuery Select2 CSS issue

Tags: css, jquery-select2

When I turned my ordinary Dropdowns into jQuery select2. But the drop down looks like the following image.

[image: Sreenshot]

And  I tried to fix the CSS alignments. But I couldnt make it work properly. Here s my js.

```
$(".combo").select2({                    
     allowClear: true,
     width: "resolve" 
});
```

Now,  I want to remove the close mark(X) and bring the dropdown symbol into the span area.

Comment: have you included the proper css , if you have , make sure there no other styles that disturbs this.

Comment: Having the dropdown open, can you please inspect the element and see the margin?

Comment: i am sure, there is no css interfere with it.

Comment: found solution for it. it was a small piece of code `padding: 0px 2px;`.  Now  I solved it.

Comment: thank you for both of your answers. it  is mistake of other css disturb,

Answer (score 2):

I hope there is some **other css styles** ***disturbing*** the `jquery select2` default styles.

[image]

Please see the default demo if the same below.

```js
$(".combo").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    width: "resolve"
});
```

```css
.combo {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="combo">
    <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
    <option value="4">Opt 4</option>
    <option value="5">Opt 5</option>
</select>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/n5hzwkp1/

Comment: i solved the problem. Anyhow I am voting it up for the help. I just solved it by removing the code which disturb it

Comment: @Akelya this could help some others , which is one of the purpose of SO !

Comment: @KevinBrown, Thanks for the advice. i have update as suggested